# Is there any way to determine Simple products that are not associated with a configurable?

Tags: configurable-product, simple-product

Is there any way to determine Simple products that are not associated with a configurable?  I want to make all simple products configurable due to the way Magento handles minimum order quantities (it automatically enters the minimum quantity for simple products, and does not for configurable s and changes the price of the item to minimum order quantity * item price, and that's confusing and an invitation to errors).

Thanks in advance for your help.  I'm looking for a non-programmatic solution.  I use the admin interface and Store Manager for Magento.

Answer (score 1):

turtledave,Magento did not provide this type on function,So without any coding or MySQL Query,you can not get the solution.

Mysql: Magento save the relation between `configurable product and it child products` at `catalog_product_super_link` and save it product basic data  at `catalog_product_entity`  Table.

[image]

Write select query with `select type_id=simple` simple product and check `that product id exit` at `catalog_product_super_link` table  `product_id.` columns.

**For getting Simple products that are not associated with a configurable**

```
    SELECT * FROM `jsw_catalog_product_entity` where entity_id 
not in (SELECT product_id FROM `jsw_catalog_product_super_link`) and type_id='simple'
```

Comment: OK, thanks a bunch.  Not sure why i didn't think to query the database.  I can do that!  I really appreciate your help.